Are Gazebo Rendering Pipeline, Shaders, and Computer Graphics Related architecture/procedures efficient?
I'm working with autonomous robots' stacks simulated in Gazebo for almost 5 years and as a Computer Scientist I also have enough understanding about CG and game engines.
What bothers me the most about Gazebo is the fact that it is infeasible to simulate and render larger and complex environments even in high-end computers, which is something everyone I've talked with complains about.
I suppose its pipeline is not optimized as it should to handle vertices and triangles. Personally, I believe that even it is is using Ogre for rendering, it does not has something as simple as Level-of-Detail (LOD), which I also believe, Ogre can handle.
The only related topic I've found regarding this was this one: https://community.gazebosim.org/t/ignition-edifice-release/893
Since Gazebo has a server client architecture, rendering simplified models in its decoupled rendering plugin should not influence the variables being used in the simulation loop. Therefore, the simulation fidelity should be maintained even with rendering optimizations.
I'm willing to give this a look and try to handle this issue, because I'm a little bit tired of working in block worlds.
Could someone enlighten me regarding this and point me to relevant related stuff?
If you also have more useful stuff related to this issue, feel free to share.
Thx

If you also have more useful stuff related to this issue, feel free to share. ... that is suitable at a forum, but not at a Q&A site like this one ... please ask a focused question
